# What are the finite quotients of the braid group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, braid-groups

Are all known finite quotients of the braid group given by reducing the Burau or Lawrence-Krammer representations mod $p$ and evaluating at some element in $\mathbb{F}_p$? I recently saw a paper giving a lower bound for the size of quotients of $B_n$, but there were no other examples and I'm trying to find some. Specifically, I'm looking at the case when $n$ is even, if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “known”. Braid groups satisfy the congruence subgroup property, which means roughly that all finite-index subgroups are pulled back from the outer automorphism groups of characteristic quotients of free groups: see https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4663v2 for details.

Comment: The group $B_3$ surjects onto $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, and hence has as quotient every finite group generated by an element of order two and an element of order three. This includes most of the finite simple groups, and in particular the Monster. For larger $n$ there are far fewer quotients, but some interesting ones are discussed in Birman and Wajnryb, "Markov classes in certain finite quotients of Artin's braid group" (1986).